# Where to place the files to be processed if I want to develop a standalone jar with clojure?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, development-environment

I want to write a standalone clojure program that will process all html files under the current working directory.

```
(println file-seq (io/file "."))
```

If I use the above code, it works when packed as a jar. But during development, where do I place the html files? Inside the `src/../core.clj` folder? I am not checking if the files are valid etc. So if I place under `src`, it will try to process `clj` files as well. Is there a better way without much change to the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the directory from which you started Java process running your Clojure code.

In case of running REPL or code or tests using your build tool (e.g. lein or boot) it is the top directory of your project (e.g. the one with project.clj or build.boot).

You can also check it by logging the absolute path of "." file:

```
(println (.getAbsolutePath (io/file ".")))
```

As to the testing of the code operating on files it is a good practice to parametrise your function with the base directory argument and call that function either with the current directory (`.`) when called as application (e.g. through the `-main` function) or by passing a stub directory prepared for testing. You could configure multiple test directories for example under `test-resources` in your project for different test scenarios (like empty directory, nested directories etc.) and call your function with a specific scenario directory as argument.

Comment: Yes. But is there way to change that? Should I add a different path if it is for development?

Comment: I think it will be better to use environment variable to handle this. One path for dev and another for production. And thanks for answering

Comment: @kadaj I have extended my answer to suggest how to handle difference in development and production environment.

Comment: Piotrek Bzdyl: Yes, passing input directory as param would work. If none is given I can default to root directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading the root dir from the command line, with "." as the default value:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
  )
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [search-path (or (first args)  ".")
        file-seq    (file-seq (io/file search-path))
       ]
    (doseq [curr-file file-seq]
      (println curr-file))))

~/clj > lein run src      # search-path => "src"
#object[java.io.File 0x5adc71e7 src]
#object[java.io.File 0x7fc5a558 src/clj]
#object[java.io.File 0x42fd8f2f src/clj/.core.clj.swp]
#object[java.io.File 0x7eea934d src/clj/core.clj]

~/clj > lein run     # search-path => "."
#object[java.io.File 0x1fc4483f .]
#object[java.io.File 0x1d7af82 ./README.md]
#object[java.io.File 0x5adc71e7 ./.lein-failures]
#object[java.io.File 0x7fc5a558 ./project.clj]
.....
```